# facing problems while using NSMenuFX-master

Tags: macos, javafx, menubar

while trying to use NSMenuFX-master, I am getting the error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class de.codecentric.centerdevice.glass.AdapterContext (in unnamed module @0x7094a739) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.tk to unnamed module @0x7094a739

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know problem with the module system and NSMenuFX. Have a look at this issue: https://github.com/codecentric/NSMenuFX/issues/29